# Using xrdp from Windows host to Ubuntu 18.04 Hyper-V VM, I cannot modify files

Tags: 18.04, 19.04, remote-desktop, file-sharing, xrdp

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.3 image (created using the Quick Create in Hyper-V Manager). The same thing happens with a 19.04 image where I've manually installed `xrdp`.

This is the "optimized" image with enhanced-session support providing clipboard integration, disk volume sharing etc. Under the hood, GUI access is via RDP.

It nearly all works. Clipboard is fine, I can see and navigate my Window C: drive etc.

I can create files in the Windows drive using the Ubuntu guest. I can remove them.  But I can't modify them. For instance,

```
cat > fred
```

works and creates fred.

```
cat >> fred
```

gives an error when I enter anything, a rather generic:

```
cat: write error: Input/output error
```

I think this has worked in the past. So I'm suspecting a Windows update, or something to do with the security on the Windows side (it's a work computer, and runs Symantec Endpoint Protection among other things).

But I don't know how to track down the issue. Ideas welcomed for what it might be, and also on what I can do to narrow down the cause.

I'm not wedded to doing this with `xrdp`. Suggestions for doing this with something else that provides the full GUI + clipboard integration + full access to host folders also welcomed.

EDIT: When I remotely access the same VM from my personal laptop I get the same issue. This does seem to rule out the work security programs. So a Windows update, or a Hyper-V or xrdp issue? No idea, currently.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know what the problem was, but a "custom" install of xrdp (so, compiled from source) using the script described here: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093 fixed it (although I no longer can get "Enhanced session" from Hyper-V and have to use the normal RDP client.

But I can read, write and modify files on the Windows host from the Ubuntu guest so I'm OK for now.